# Track property do not work properly with Object methods

Tags: lightning-web-components, js, track, proxy

**Setup:**

```js
@track
states = {
    first: true,
    second: false
};
```

**What I'm trying to achieve:**
I want to check if `this.states` has any `true` values.

**What I've tried**

```js
Object.values(this.states).some(v => v === true);
```

**What I've noticed:**
I've noticed that:
`Object.values` `Object.keys` `Object.entries` always returns for me an empty array, although the states object itself is not empty.

**My question is:**
What can be the cause? I've seen that @track properties are basically encapsulating object into Proxy object.
How can I get all of the values of `this.states` object?

**UPDATE 1:**
Okay so it does not seem to work **only** with my **getter** which toggles visibility of my div.

```js
get isDivDisplayed() {
    return Object.values(this.states).some((v) => v);
}
```

```html
<div if:true={isDivDisplayed}>something</div>
```

Comment: This seems to be working, when adding `let hasTrue = Object.values(this.states).some(v => v === true);` in `connectedCallback()`, I am able to get `hasTrue` as true. Could you add more code for us to be able to replicate the issue?

Comment: update in description

Comment: That is working as well. Could you share an example on- https://webcomponents.dev/create/lwc

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine for me. Check below piece of code:-

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class Summer21 extends LightningElement {
    @track states = {
        first: true,
        second: false
    };

    connectedCallback(){
        console.log(Object.values(this.states).some(v => v === true));
        console.log(Object.keys(this.states));
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this.states)) {
            console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
        }
    }
}
```

When i place the component on the page, I see these results:-

[image]